# Is it possible to use the LevenbergMarquardt algorithm for fitting a black-box residual function?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I have a black-box multiargument multiparametric function of the type `SRD[dataPoint_List,params_List]` which accepts experimental data along with the parameters of the model and returns a vector with the first element being the squared relative deviation (SRD) between the computed model value and experimental value for the given data point and the rest of the elements being the gradient of the SRD in the given point with respect to `params`. I wish to minimize the sum `Sum[First[SRD[dataPoint, params]], {dataPoint, dataPoints}]` with respect to `params` using the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm and the computed gradient of `SRD` with respect to `params` (equal to `Sum[Rest[SRD[dataPoint, params]], {dataPoint, dataPoints}]`). What is the best way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I'll only note that `Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"` [can take `"Jacobian"` and `"Residual"` options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationGaussNewtonMethods.html#204030633), which you should look into.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution based on Faysal's code:

```
steps=0; 
FindMinimum[Null,
 {optimVariables, initialGuess}\[Transpose],
 Method -> {"LevenbergMarquardt", 
   "Residual" -> Sqrt[2] residualVector[optimVariables], 
   "Jacobian" -> {Sqrt[2] jacobianMatrix[optimVariables], EvaluationMonitor :> ++steps}, 
   "StepControl" -> {"TrustRegion", "StartingScaledStepSize" -> 1/1000, "MaxScaledStepSize" -> 1/10, "AcceptableStepRatio" -> 1/3}}]
```

Note that it is recommended to use exact numbers for the parameters of the `"TrustRegion"` method because these parameters are used inside of the algorithm without any check for consistency with `WorkingPrecision`. I should also note that the actual residual vector and jacobian must be multiplied by `Sqrt[2]` for having `FindMinimum` returning the minimum equal to

```
residualVector[optimVariables].residualVector[optimVariables]
```

and not to

```
residualVector[optimVariables].residualVector[optimVariables]/2
```

as it is by default.

The jacobian may be calculated automatically by the following code:

```
jacobianMatrix[_] = D[residualVector[optimVariables], {optimVariables}]
```

One can restrict the jacobian to be evaluated for numerical values only by defining it as:

```
jacobianMatrix[_List?(VectorQ[#, NumberQ] &)] = 
    D[residualVector[optimVariables], {optimVariables}]
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar situation once, here's a prototype similar to your problem that I wrote once on the Mathematica forum of LinkedIn, you can adapt it to your needs, the gradient is computed using the "Residual" option of the Method option.

```
targets={1,2};

f[{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}]:={(x-3)^5,2 (y-5)^3};
objectiveFunction[{params___?NumericQ}]:=Norm[f[{params}]-targets,2];
R[{params___?NumericQ}]:=f[{params}]-targets;

OptimVariables={Symbol["xx"],Symbol["yy"]};
initialGuess={1,-1};

FindMinimum[
   objectiveFunction[OptimVariables]
   ,
   {OptimVariables,initialGuess}\[Transpose]
   ,
   Method->{"LevenbergMarquardt","Residual"->R[OptimVariables]}
]
```