# the winding number for the circle map (Arnold tongue)

Tags: arbitrary-precision

I want to perform an iterative calculation and visualize the results:

```
f[n_, a_, b_] := Nest[# + a - b Sin[2 π #] &, 0, n]/n;
```

If I use machine precision, it probably results in greater error, for example:

```
N@f[500, 1/2, 3/5]
f[500, 0.5, 0.6]

(* 0.5 *)
(* 0.0282658 *)
```

Most of the time we can't use infinite precision and have to resort to using `N`.

**How can I  increase the accuracy of the results?**

In addition, the iterative calculation is already quite slow, so it is also important to think about the efficiency of the solution.

I got started on this question while trying to explore properties of [Circle Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_map), and I would like to reproduce this image from the link:

[image]

My initial attempt looks like this:

```
f = Compile[{n, a, k}, Nest[# + a - k Sin[2 \[Pi] #] &, 0, n]/n];
dat =Outer[f[500, #2, #] &, Range[0, 1, 1/500], Range[0, 1, 1/500]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ArrayPlot[dat, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, #] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
```

Which gives the following (unsatisfactory) result:

[image]

Comment: `f[500, N[5/10, 880], N[6/10, 880]]` ?

Comment: @chris It works, but will be very slow...

Comment: It's already very slow.. :) Cool picture though :)

Comment: If you want to speed up you'll need `Compile` thus won't have the high precision..

Comment: OT: This may give you a slightly faster result, though doesn't resolve you problem: `f=Compile[{{n,_Integer},{z,_Complex}},Module[{a=Re[z],k=Im[z]},Nest[#+a-k Sin[2π#]&,0,n]/n],CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},Parallelization->True];data=Outer[#2+#1I&,Range[0,1,1/500],Range[0,1,1/500]];dat=f[1000,data];//AbsoluteTiming`. I think you can generalize your question to attract more attention, maybe something like *How to have both high precision and performance*..

Comment: where \theta is to be interpreted as polar angle such that its value lies between 0 and 1.  have you tried shifting the result on each iteration?

Comment: after taking a deeper look, I think someone with sufficient expertise should clarify what the "is to be interpreted" statement is supposed to mean on the wikipedia page..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have figured out why you are getting the structure you are getting.  The reason has to do with your initial choice of the angle, which you set at $0$ in the `Nest[]` statement.  The actual image is generated by choosing the mean result of iterating the map for many initial values chosen uniformly at random in $[0,1]$.

With $n = 50$ iterations and $m = 20$ trials, I obtained the following image using the following modification of your code:

```
f = Compile[{n, m, a, k}, Mean[Table[Nest[# + a - k Sin[2 Pi #] &,
    RandomReal[], n]/n, {j, 1, m}]]];
dat = Parallelize[Outer[f[50, 20, #2, #] &, Range[0, 1, 1/1000], 
    Range[0, 1, 1/1000]]];
```

I believe this is very, very close to exactly what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Nice work!Thanks!

Comment: If you use `RandomReal[1, m]` instead of the `Table[……]`, the code'll be about one time faster :)

Comment: good call +1!.  Can you generate a figure showing regions where the result is "essentially" independent of the input?

Comment: @xzczd I can't claim to be especially proficient at *Mathematica* programming, but your suggested modification won't compile because the evaluation of `Nest[]` would proceed on a list.

Comment: @xzczd : works for me (and about 50% faster ). `Mean[Nest[# + a - k Sin[2 Pi #] &, RandomReal[1, Round[m]], Round[n]]/n]`

Comment: Is that command **compiled?**  If so, show the complete code.

Comment: @heropup Oh, seems that it's necessary to declare the type of `m` in this case (I added those declarations habitually in my code so didn't notice this) : `f = Compile[{n, {m, _Integer}, a, k}, Mean[Nest[# + a - k Sin[2 Pi #] &, RandomReal[1, m], n]]/n];`

Comment: And wraping `m` with `Round` as @george2079 suggested is also a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I learned something new today ^_^

Answer (score 11):

This question looks as a duplicate of these questions:

[How to create internally optimized expression for computing with high `WorkingPrecision`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25432/280)

[How to work with `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/280)

An internally optimized version of the original function can be created as follows:

```
n = 500;
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{a, b}, 
   Unevaluated[Nest[# + a - b Sin[2 \[Pi] #] &, 0, n]/n], {}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 880];
```

How the created `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` should be used:

```
f[{1/10, 1/5}]
```

> ```
> 0.00016666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666\
> 6666666666666666666666666666666666666666664685468521373229053036940442\
> 3962701216291153088605786704858607575162427563183707930229553541195321\
> 2101361759645135515775432980342040381738861309064752553797366691813555\
> 0017169360630698662587053257997111846801265386183928858616194265489581\
> 2949120884649269257779567658163657155358878262590630724222855526137604\
> 688700110160340115203634767418946813394731969
> ```

Here is a comparison of performance (updated):

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
ff[a_, b_] := Nest[# + a - b Sin[2 \[Pi] #] &, 0, n]/n;
o1 = ff[1/100, 1/500]; // AccurateTiming
o2 = ff[0.01`880, 1/500]; // AccurateTiming
o3 = f[{1/100, 1/500}]; // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 3.603673
> 0.0668274
> 0.068519
> ```

```
o2 == o3
```

> True

As one can see from the timings, unfortunately in this concrete case `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` does not increase performance as compared to the inexact case (`o2`) based on pure `Nest`.

It means that the only way to increase performance of computing the `ArrayPlot` is to use [parallelization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html). According to the documentation, "`Outer` products automatically parallelize" by `Parallelize` so the code in the question can be modified in straightforward way:

```
dat = Parallelize[Outer[f[500, #2, #] &, Range[0, 1.`880, 1/500], Range[0, 1.`880, 1/500]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ArrayPlot[dat, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, #] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
```

---

But even without parallelization it is possible to plot the problematic region in a reasonable time with precision 100 (MMa 8.0.4):

```
f[n_, a_, b_] := Nest[# + a - b Sin[2 \[Pi] #] &, 0, n]/n;

n = 500; prec = 100;
dat = Outer[f[n, #2, #] &, N[Range[4/10, 85/100, 1/n], prec], 
    N[Range[3/10, 7/10, 1/n], prec]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ArrayPlot[dat, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
```

> {501.2916722, Null}
>
> [image: plot]

And here is the result with `prec = 300`:

> {1109.0984368, Null}
>
> [image: plot2]

Comment: That's not a fair comparison though, as `ff[1/100,1/500]` will compute the exact solution. Try `ff@@SetPrecision[{1/100, 1/500}, 880];//AbsoluteTiming`! For me the timing differences are negligible.

Comment: @sebhofer Feel free to edit my answer and add extended timing comparison. I cannot test extensively right now.

Comment: Ok, put my timings there. (The original timings were different for me, so I exchanged all of them. Hope that's ok.)

Comment: Its OK. So your comparison shows that ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` with `Unevaluated` `Nest` inside does not increase performance. I can propose removing `Unevaluated`. It will increase time for creation of ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` but possibly can give better performance. Still cannot check this suggestion myself.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't want to expand the nested expression for `n=500`. Only machines with a lot of memory will be able to handle it.

Comment: The comparison will be correct if auto-compilation for `Nest` is turned on. So after setting `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"NestCompileLength" -> 49}]` it will be sufficient to compare timings for `n=50`.

Comment: @sebhofer I just have performed quick test for `n=25` with expanded `Nest` and found that ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` does not give any performance improvement.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know there is a third `Timing` function.

Comment: Have you plotted this?  I still get a result that looks more like @Chenminqi's initial result that the figure on the wiki page.  (I'm beginning to doubt the validity of the wiki page figure in the neighborhood of `a~1/2 , b~3/5` )

Answer (score 9):

Incidentally, here is a higher resolution picture of the image produced by heropup's answer, plotted over both positive and negative values of the two circle map parameters:

[image]

Blue represents negative, yellow represents positive.

You can view a far larger 6001x6001 pixel image (about 29MB) [here](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7404/16495153571_e8c9d1780e_o.png).

Here is the code used to generate the upper right quarter of the image (execution time with a 4-core i5-3550 was around 90 minutes):

```
f = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {k, _Real}}, 
   Mean[Table[
     Nest[# + a - k Sin[2 Pi #] &, j/1600 + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/6400], 
       50]/50, {j, 1600}]], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
{tim, dat} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Parallelize[
    Outer[f[#2, #] &, N@Range[0, 3, 1/1000], N@Range[0, 3, 1/1000]]]];
Export["ArnoldTongue.h5", dat]
```

Instead of averaging over random seed values between 0 and 1, this averages uniformly over the interval $[0,1]$ with a slight random noise added in; this accelerates the convergence to a smooth final image as compared to using random seeds, and thus reduces compute time.

The other 3/4 of the image can then be recovered by symmetry and antisymmetry. The resulting data was colored and rendered in Julia.

Comment: Can you add the specific parameters for the producing of this picture? BTW, the link is broken.

Comment: @xzczd: I added the code used to produce the image. The image link worked for me, but I changed it to a direct link to the PNG file just in case others also have trouble.

Answer (score 8):

not an answer, just a cool animation:

[image: looping]

Looping over the initial seed values from 0-1