# Plotting Arnold tongues

Tags: plotting

I would like to understand how can I plot [`Arnold tongues`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_tongue) (see figure below) with help of Wolfram Mathematica.

[image]

From [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56499/the-winding-number-for-the-circle-map-arnold-tongue), I have borrowed the function that computes the winding number of the circle map. My own version (in order to be consistent with the figure presented above) is

```
WindingNumber = 
  Compile[{n, η, ϵ, ϕ0}, (Nest[# + η + ϵ*Sin[#] &, ϕ0, n] - ϕ0)/(2*Pi*n)];
```

Here, `η` is the parameter, `ϕ0` is the initial value and `ϵ` is the parameter, too. I know that each Arnold tongue corresponds to the rational value of `WindingNumber`. So, my idea is to check that for a given values of `ϵ` and `η` is rational or not. To do it, I need the Wolfram Mathematica analog of `RationalQ` function (see discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/why-no-rationalq-or-realq)). As I understand, there is no analog of `RationalQ` function, but in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/how-to-check-if-an-expression-is-a-real-valued-number), I see the naive realization:

```
TrueQ@Element[x, Rationals]
```

where (as I understand) one checks that `x` belongs to `Rationals` (or not). So, I have tried to create a grid of parameters `η` and `ϵ` with help of `Table`. For each point of the grid, I check is `WindingNumber` rational or not with the help of the function written above. If true, I mark this point by 1, if false, I mark by 0, so I write

```
ArnoldTongues = Table[{ϵ, 2*Pi*i, 
    If[TrueQ@Element[WindingNumber [100, 2*Pi*i, 1.0, 0], Rationals], 1, 
     0]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}, {ϵ, 0, 1, 0.01}];
```

As a result, I have the array that is suitable for `ListDensityPlot`.

**However, I obtain that the winding number is always irrational for every point on my grid, which is impossible. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: @ChrisK , I have updated the question, now everything seems consistent

Comment: Your function `WindingNumber` only returns real numbers. Mathematica does not consider any real number to be rational. Only explicit ratios of integers are considered rational. Compare `TrueQ@Element[0.25, Rationals]` with `TrueQ@Element[1/4, Rationals]`

Comment: @BobHanlon , okey, I can try `Rationalize`. But it seems useless. Does any other approach to visualize Arnold tongues in Wolfram Mathematica exist?

Comment: You can just `Cases[wnums, wnum_ ;/ Abs[wnum - ratonal] < tol]` for each rational you want and some tol, e.g. 1E-4

Comment: @I.M. , so, first I generate list of `wnums` and compare each element with a given `rational` with the predefined tolereance `tol`? Does it mean that I have to generate list of rationals, too?

Comment: There is a nice demo of Arnold tongues at the Wolfram Demonstration project: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ArnoldTongues/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(* Set compitation target, use "WVM" if no C compiler is avaliable *)
ClearAll[target] ;
target = "C" ;
ClearAll[windingNumber];
windingNumber = Compile[
    {{n,_Integer},{eta,_Real},{epsilon,_Real},{phi,_Real}},
    (Nest[# + eta + epsilon*Sin[#] &, phi, n] - phi)/(2*Pi*n),
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    CompilationTarget -> target,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Generate wnums on a rectangular eta-epsilon grid:

```
(* Set number of iterations and grid size *)
n = 10^3;
m = 5*10^3;

(* Generate grid *)
eta = 2*Pi*Subdivide[0.0, 1.0, m - 1] ;
epsilon = Subdivide[0.0, 1.0, m - 1] ;

(* Set initial condition *)
phi = 0.0 ;

(* Compute winding numbers *)
wnums = Reverse[Table[windingNumber[n, eta, eps, phi], {eps, epsilon}]] ;
```

Plot all values:

```
(* Plot all winding numbers *)
ArrayPlot[wnums, DataRange -> {MinMax[eta], MinMax[epsilon]}, FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, ImageSize -> 900, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Filter and plot tongues:

```
(* Select close to a rational with a given tolerance *)
tol = 10.^-3;
rationals = {0, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 1} ;
ClearAll[select] ;
select[tol_, list_, rational_] := N[UnitStep[Clip[Abs[list - rational], {0.0, tol}, {-1.0, -1.0}]]] ; 
tongues = Fold[Plus, Map[select[tol, wnums, #] &, rationals]] ;
ArrayPlot[tongues, DataRange -> {MinMax[eta], MinMax[epsilon]}, FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {True, None}}, ImageSize -> 900, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much for this answer