# Is there any way to use compile and still maintain high precision in Mathematica?

Tags: compile, precision-and-accuracy

Is there any way to use compile and still maintain Arbitrary-precision like 50 in Mathematica?

Comment: Thanks, I am new here,so I am still trying to figure out how this site works. Great site!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to optimize numerical expressions for computing with arbitrary precision using undocumented `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` framework, see details in these threads:

- [How to work with Experimental`NumericalFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/280)
- [How to create internally optimized expression for computing with high WorkingPrecision?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25432/280)