# Is there any alternative for conditional plot that gives a more precise result in a shorter time?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, conditional, machine-precision

I have the given function $Func$ and want to have a plot of those domains where $-3\leq Func\leq 3$ in precise details. I am using `Plot[ConditionalExpression[1, -3 <= Func <= 3]` for and I obtain this plot

[image]

**Questions**.

1. As can be seen, by increasing `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, and `WorkingPrecision`, the accuracy of the plots changes; however, when I set the mentioned items a big number, it takes a lot of time. My question is: is there any alternative rather than a conditional plot that gives a more precise result in a shorter time?

```
p1 = Plot[ConditionalExpression[1, -3 <= Func <= 3], {x, 11, 16}, PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.005]], Axes -> {False, False}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] ;
p2 = Plot[ConditionalExpression[2, -3 <= Func <= 3], {x, 11, 16}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.005]], Axes -> {False, False}, WorkingPrecision -> 100] ;
p3 = Plot[ConditionalExpression[3, -3 <= Func <= 3], {x, 11, 16}, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 6, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.005]], Axes -> {False, False}, WorkingPrecision -> 200] ;

Pic = Show[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> {{11, 16}, {0, 4}} ,  AspectRatio -> 1/6]
```

the function

```
Func:=(1/(1024*(-1 + x)^11*(1 + x)^11))*Csc[x]^11*(-264*x*(-1 + x^2)^2*(777 + 11928*x^2 + 73148*x^4 + 275752*x^6 + 653046*x^8 + 275752*x^10 + 73148*x^12 + 11928*x^14 + 777*x^16)*Cos[Pi/22] - 88*x*(-1 + x^2)^4*(69 + 2258*x^2 - 7733*x^4 - 132548*x^6 - 7733*x^8 + 2258*x^10 + 69*x^12)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22] + 88*x*(-1 + x^2)^6*(183 + 2532*x^2 - 7990*x^4 + 2532*x^6 + 183*x^8)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Cos[(5/22)*(Pi - 88*x)] + 
   22*(13031 + 2359*x + 94165*x^2 + 27282*x^3 + 247529*x^4 + 152299*x^5 + 424547*x^6 + 605784*x^7 + 1019270*x^8 + 1805534*x^9 + 2133618*x^10 + 2677804*x^11 + 2133618*x^12 + 1805534*x^13 + 1019270*x^14 + 605784*x^15 + 424547*x^16 + 152299*x^17 + 247529*x^18 + 27282*x^19 + 94165*x^20 + 2359*x^21 + 13031*x^22)*Cos[(5/22)*(Pi - 44*x)] - 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Cos[Pi/22 - 18*x] + 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 18*x] + 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Cos[Pi/22 - 16*x] + 
   176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 16*x] - 264*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(69 + 1298*x^2 + 3019*x^4 + 3516*x^6 + 3019*x^8 + 1298*x^10 + 69*x^12)*Cos[Pi/22 - 14*x] + 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(413 - 8*x + 7762*x^2 - 40*x^3 + 18099*x^4 + 48*x^5 + 21180*x^6 + 48*x^7 + 18099*x^8 - 40*x^9 + 7762*x^10 - 8*x^11 + 413*x^12)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 14*x] - 1056*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^4*(17 - 2*x + 301*x^2 - 8*x^3 + 450*x^4 + 20*x^5 + 450*x^6 - 8*x^7 + 301*x^8 - 2*x^9 + 17*x^10)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 14*x] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24547 - 48*x + 135563*x^2 - 192*x^3 + 343804*x^4 + 576*x^5 + 563948*x^6 + 192*x^7 + 701610*x^8 - 1056*x^9 + 701610*x^10 + 192*x^11 + 563948*x^12 + 576*x^13 + 343804*x^14 - 192*x^15 + 135563*x^16 - 48*x^17 + 24547*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 - 12*x] - 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12691 - 363*x + 108935*x^2 - 4480*x^3 + 375232*x^4 - 18340*x^5 + 763352*x^6 + 2752*x^7 + 1099086*x^8 + 40862*x^9 + 1099086*x^10 + 2752*x^11 + 763352*x^12 - 18340*x^13 + 375232*x^14 - 4480*x^15 + 108935*x^16 - 363*x^17 + 12691*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 10*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16295 + 167*x + 72447*x^2 + 488*x^3 + 155964*x^4 + 2180*x^5 + 251340*x^6 + 12888*x^7 + 290386*x^8 - 31446*x^9 + 290386*x^10 + 12888*x^11 + 251340*x^12 + 2180*x^13 + 155964*x^14 + 488*x^15 + 72447*x^16 + 167*x^17 + 16295*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 - 8*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16373 + 999*x + 76477*x^2 + 13080*x^3 + 189364*x^4 + 72932*x^5 + 386276*x^6 + 270888*x^7 + 707766*x^8 + 463850*x^9 + 707766*x^10 + 270888*x^11 + 386276*x^12 + 72932*x^13 + 189364*x^14 + 13080*x^15 + 76477*x^16 + 999*x^17 + 16373*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 8*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16015 - 2003*x + 63751*x^2 - 28840*x^3 + 78204*x^4 - 179860*x^5 - 134196*x^6 - 651928*x^7 - 613598*x^8 - 1027250*x^9 - 613598*x^10 - 651928*x^11 - 134196*x^12 - 179860*x^13 + 78204*x^14 - 28840*x^15 + 63751*x^16 - 2003*x^17 + 16015*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 8*x] - 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52199 - 345*x + 315499*x^2 - 10560*x^3 + 899168*x^4 - 54156*x^5 + 1682776*x^6 - 112896*x^7 + 2555382*x^8 + 355914*x^9 + 2555382*x^10 - 112896*x^11 + 1682776*x^12 - 54156*x^13 + 899168*x^14 - 10560*x^15 + 315499*x^16 - 345*x^17 + 52199*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 - 6*x] + 
   22*(52771 + 4399*x + 234321*x^2 + 52642*x^3 + 475893*x^4 + 275331*x^5 + 786607*x^6 + 982808*x^7 + 1480446*x^8 + 3255374*x^9 + 4834282*x^10 + 6587532*x^11 + 4834282*x^12 + 3255374*x^13 + 1480446*x^14 + 982808*x^15 + 786607*x^16 + 275331*x^17 + 475893*x^18 + 52642*x^19 + 234321*x^20 + 4399*x^21 + 52771*x^22)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 6*x] - 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(51891 - 3691*x + 305759*x^2 - 47488*x^3 + 827048*x^4 - 208292*x^5 + 1552080*x^6 - 13632*x^7 + 2768246*x^8 + 546206*x^9 + 2768246*x^10 - 13632*x^11 + 1552080*x^12 - 208292*x^13 + 827048*x^14 - 47488*x^15 + 305759*x^16 - 3691*x^17 + 51891*x^18)*
    Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 6*x] - 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(72015 + 6240*x + 310551*x^2 + 102720*x^3 + 813036*x^4 + 590592*x^5 + 2145436*x^6 + 2003648*x^7 + 4916498*x^8 + 5603648*x^9 + 4916498*x^10 + 2003648*x^11 + 2145436*x^12 + 590592*x^13 + 813036*x^14 + 102720*x^15 + 310551*x^16 + 6240*x^17 + 72015*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 - 4*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(70013 - 9616*x + 231445*x^2 - 142464*x^3 + 145220*x^4 - 945600*x^5 - 1033516*x^6 - 3497856*x^7 - 4918186*x^8 - 7324000*x^9 - 4918186*x^10 - 3497856*x^11 - 1033516*x^12 - 945600*x^13 + 145220*x^14 - 142464*x^15 + 231445*x^16 - 9616*x^17 + 70013*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 4*x] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71223 + 3024*x + 285567*x^2 + 16512*x^3 + 555340*x^4 - 123712*x^5 + 438524*x^6 - 275584*x^7 + 1401858*x^8 + 759520*x^9 + 1401858*x^10 - 275584*x^11 + 438524*x^12 - 123712*x^13 + 555340*x^14 + 16512*x^15 + 285567*x^16 + 3024*x^17 + 71223*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 4*x] + 44*(49997 + 3621*x + 173407*x^2 + 48822*x^3 + 294011*x^4 + 230337*x^5 + 476033*x^6 + 635912*x^7 + 1205090*x^8 + 1392922*x^9 + 3306486*x^10 + 6386820*x^11 + 3306486*x^12 + 1392922*x^13 + 1205090*x^14 + 635912*x^15 + 476033*x^16 + 230337*x^17 + 294011*x^18 + 48822*x^19 + 173407*x^20 + 3621*x^21 + 49997*x^22)*
    Cos[Pi/22 - 2*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49568 - 1083*x + 257024*x^2 - 17792*x^3 + 651936*x^4 - 90468*x^5 + 1160160*x^6 - 177472*x^7 + 2010080*x^8 + 573630*x^9 + 2010080*x^10 - 177472*x^11 + 1160160*x^12 - 90468*x^13 + 651936*x^14 - 17792*x^15 + 257024*x^16 - 1083*x^17 + 49568*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 - 2*x] + 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49667 - 129*x + 262895*x^2 - 4800*x^3 + 697256*x^4 - 21740*x^5 + 1364304*x^6 + 96384*x^7 + 1754646*x^8 - 139430*x^9 + 1754646*x^10 + 96384*x^11 + 1364304*x^12 - 21740*x^13 + 697256*x^14 - 4800*x^15 + 262895*x^16 - 129*x^17 + 49667*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 - 2*x] - 
   44*(-1 + x)^2*(49997 + 96373*x + 316156*x^2 + 487117*x^3 + 952089*x^4 + 1186724*x^5 + 1897392*x^6 + 1972148*x^7 + 3251994*x^8 + 3138918*x^9 + 6332328*x^10 + 3138918*x^11 + 3251994*x^12 + 1972148*x^13 + 1897392*x^14 + 1186724*x^15 + 952089*x^16 + 487117*x^17 + 316156*x^18 + 96373*x^19 + 49997*x^20)*Cos[Pi/22 + 2*x] + 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49568 + 1083*x + 257024*x^2 + 17792*x^3 + 651936*x^4 + 90468*x^5 + 1160160*x^6 + 177472*x^7 + 2010080*x^8 - 573630*x^9 + 2010080*x^10 + 177472*x^11 + 1160160*x^12 + 90468*x^13 + 651936*x^14 + 17792*x^15 + 257024*x^16 + 1083*x^17 + 49568*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 2*x] - 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49667 + 129*x + 262895*x^2 + 4800*x^3 + 697256*x^4 + 21740*x^5 + 1364304*x^6 - 96384*x^7 + 1754646*x^8 + 139430*x^9 + 1754646*x^10 - 96384*x^11 + 1364304*x^12 + 21740*x^13 + 697256*x^14 + 4800*x^15 + 262895*x^16 + 129*x^17 + 49667*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 2*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(72015 - 6240*x + 310551*x^2 - 102720*x^3 + 813036*x^4 - 590592*x^5 + 2145436*x^6 - 2003648*x^7 + 4916498*x^8 - 5603648*x^9 + 4916498*x^10 - 2003648*x^11 + 2145436*x^12 - 590592*x^13 + 813036*x^14 - 102720*x^15 + 310551*x^16 - 6240*x^17 + 72015*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 + 4*x] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(70013 + 9616*x + 231445*x^2 + 142464*x^3 + 145220*x^4 + 945600*x^5 - 1033516*x^6 + 3497856*x^7 - 4918186*x^8 + 7324000*x^9 - 4918186*x^10 + 3497856*x^11 - 1033516*x^12 + 945600*x^13 + 145220*x^14 + 142464*x^15 + 231445*x^16 + 9616*x^17 + 70013*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 4*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71223 - 3024*x + 285567*x^2 - 16512*x^3 + 555340*x^4 + 123712*x^5 + 438524*x^6 + 275584*x^7 + 1401858*x^8 - 759520*x^9 + 1401858*x^10 + 275584*x^11 + 438524*x^12 + 123712*x^13 + 555340*x^14 - 16512*x^15 + 285567*x^16 - 3024*x^17 + 71223*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 4*x] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52199 + 345*x + 315499*x^2 + 10560*x^3 + 899168*x^4 + 54156*x^5 + 1682776*x^6 + 112896*x^7 + 2555382*x^8 - 355914*x^9 + 2555382*x^10 + 112896*x^11 + 1682776*x^12 + 54156*x^13 + 899168*x^14 + 10560*x^15 + 315499*x^16 + 345*x^17 + 52199*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 + 6*x] - 22*(-1 + x)^2*(52771 + 101143*x + 383836*x^2 + 613887*x^3 + 1319831*x^4 + 1750444*x^5 + 2967664*x^6 + 3202076*x^7 + 4916934*x^8 + 3376418*x^9 + 6670184*x^10 + 3376418*x^11 + 4916934*x^12 + 3202076*x^13 + 2967664*x^14 + 1750444*x^15 + 1319831*x^16 + 613887*x^17 + 383836*x^18 + 101143*x^19 + 52771*x^20)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 6*x] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(51891 + 3691*x + 305759*x^2 + 47488*x^3 + 827048*x^4 + 208292*x^5 + 1552080*x^6 + 13632*x^7 + 2768246*x^8 - 546206*x^9 + 2768246*x^10 + 13632*x^11 + 1552080*x^12 + 208292*x^13 + 827048*x^14 + 47488*x^15 + 305759*x^16 + 3691*x^17 + 51891*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 6*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16295 - 167*x + 72447*x^2 - 488*x^3 + 155964*x^4 - 2180*x^5 + 251340*x^6 - 12888*x^7 + 290386*x^8 + 31446*x^9 + 290386*x^10 - 12888*x^11 + 251340*x^12 - 2180*x^13 + 155964*x^14 - 488*x^15 + 72447*x^16 - 167*x^17 + 16295*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 + 8*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16373 - 999*x + 76477*x^2 - 13080*x^3 + 189364*x^4 - 72932*x^5 + 386276*x^6 - 270888*x^7 + 707766*x^8 - 463850*x^9 + 707766*x^10 - 270888*x^11 + 386276*x^12 - 72932*x^13 + 189364*x^14 - 13080*x^15 + 76477*x^16 - 999*x^17 + 16373*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 8*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16015 + 2003*x + 63751*x^2 + 28840*x^3 + 78204*x^4 + 179860*x^5 - 134196*x^6 + 651928*x^7 - 613598*x^8 + 1027250*x^9 - 613598*x^10 + 651928*x^11 - 134196*x^12 + 179860*x^13 + 78204*x^14 + 28840*x^15 + 63751*x^16 + 2003*x^17 + 16015*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 8*x] - 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12691 + 163*x + 109863*x^2 + 832*x^3 + 383904*x^4 + 1732*x^5 + 782968*x^6 - 2688*x^7 + 1069870*x^8 - 78*x^9 + 1069870*x^10 - 2688*x^11 + 782968*x^12 + 1732*x^13 + 383904*x^14 + 832*x^15 + 109863*x^16 + 163*x^17 + 12691*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 + 10*x] + 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12691 + 363*x + 108935*x^2 + 4480*x^3 + 375232*x^4 + 18340*x^5 + 763352*x^6 - 2752*x^7 + 1099086*x^8 - 40862*x^9 + 1099086*x^10 - 2752*x^11 + 763352*x^12 + 18340*x^13 + 375232*x^14 + 4480*x^15 + 108935*x^16 + 363*x^17 + 12691*x^18)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 10*x] + 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24547 + 48*x + 135563*x^2 + 192*x^3 + 343804*x^4 - 576*x^5 + 563948*x^6 - 192*x^7 + 701610*x^8 + 1056*x^9 + 701610*x^10 - 192*x^11 + 563948*x^12 - 576*x^13 + 343804*x^14 + 192*x^15 + 135563*x^16 + 48*x^17 + 24547*x^18)*Cos[Pi/22 + 12*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24747 - 1472*x + 141523*x^2 - 16640*x^3 + 386524*x^4 - 96000*x^5 + 742092*x^6 - 278272*x^7 + 1064410*x^8 - 394880*x^9 + 1064410*x^10 - 278272*x^11 + 742092*x^12 - 96000*x^13 + 386524*x^14 - 16640*x^15 + 141523*x^16 - 1472*x^17 + 24747*x^18)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 12*x] + 
   264*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(69 + 1298*x^2 + 3019*x^4 + 3516*x^6 + 3019*x^8 + 1298*x^10 + 69*x^12)*Cos[Pi/22 + 14*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(413 + 8*x + 7762*x^2 + 40*x^3 + 18099*x^4 - 48*x^5 + 21180*x^6 - 48*x^7 + 18099*x^8 + 40*x^9 + 7762*x^10 + 8*x^11 + 413*x^12)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 14*x] + 1056*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^4*(17 + 2*x + 301*x^2 + 8*x^3 + 450*x^4 - 20*x^5 + 450*x^6 + 8*x^7 + 301*x^8 + 2*x^9 + 17*x^10)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 14*x] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Cos[Pi/22 + 16*x] + 
   176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 16*x] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 16*x] + 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Cos[Pi/22 + 18*x] - 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 18*x] + 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Cos[(5*Pi)/22 + 18*x] + 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Cos[Pi/22 + 20*x] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Cos[(3*Pi)/22 + 20*x] - 
   22*(-1 + x)^2*(13031 + 23703*x + 128540*x^2 + 206095*x^3 + 531179*x^4 + 703964*x^5 + 1301296*x^6 + 1292844*x^7 + 2303662*x^8 + 1508946*x^9 + 2847848*x^10 + 1508946*x^11 + 2303662*x^12 + 1292844*x^13 + 1301296*x^14 + 703964*x^15 + 531179*x^16 + 206095*x^17 + 128540*x^18 + 23703*x^19 + 13031*x^20)*Cos[(5/22)*(Pi + 44*x)] - 44*(-1 + x)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(473 + 498*x + 9059*x^2 + 13716*x^3 + 30401*x^4 + 26670*x^5 + 54275*x^6 + 24728*x^7 + 54275*x^8 + 26670*x^9 + 30401*x^10 + 13716*x^11 + 9059*x^12 + 498*x^13 + 473*x^14)*Cos[(7/22)*(Pi + 44*x)] + 
   5632*(-1 + x)^2*x*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 6*x - 6*x^2 - 6*x^3 + x^4)*Cos[(9/22)*(Pi + 44*x)] - 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24569 - 64*x + 135985*x^2 - 512*x^3 + 345204*x^4 - 2816*x^5 + 565188*x^6 + 512*x^7 + 698526*x^8 + 5760*x^9 + 698526*x^10 + 512*x^11 + 565188*x^12 - 2816*x^13 + 345204*x^14 - 512*x^15 + 135985*x^16 - 64*x^17 + 24569*x^18)*Cos[(3/22)*(Pi + 88*x)] + 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Cos[(5/22)*(Pi + 88*x)] - 176*x*(-1 + x^2)^8*(31 - 14*x^2 + 31*x^4)*Sin[Pi/11] - 88*x*(-1 + x^2)^6*(399 - 604*x^2 + 1690*x^4 - 604*x^6 + 399*x^8)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11] - 
   704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi - 99*x)] + 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(249 - 16*x + 668*x^2 - 112*x^3 + 470*x^4 - 112*x^5 + 668*x^6 - 16*x^7 + 249*x^8)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi - 88*x)] - 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(23859 + 5056*x + 114715*x^2 + 69376*x^3 + 157564*x^4 + 406272*x^5 - 170772*x^6 + 1110272*x^7 - 715190*x^8 + 1536640*x^9 - 715190*x^10 + 1110272*x^11 - 170772*x^12 + 406272*x^13 + 157564*x^14 + 69376*x^15 + 114715*x^16 + 5056*x^17 + 23859*x^18)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi - 66*x)] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12221 + 3473*x + 96577*x^2 + 38720*x^3 + 312232*x^4 + 91180*x^5 + 724000*x^6 - 37632*x^7 + 1214266*x^8 - 191482*x^9 + 1214266*x^10 - 37632*x^11 + 724000*x^12 + 91180*x^13 + 312232*x^14 + 38720*x^15 + 96577*x^16 + 3473*x^17 + 12221*x^18)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi - 55*x)] + 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[Pi/11 - 20*x] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 - 20*x] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(221 + 176*x + 76*x^2 + 976*x^3 - 850*x^4 + 976*x^5 + 76*x^6 + 176*x^7 + 221*x^8)*Sin[Pi/11 - 16*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(163 + 1336*x + 4846*x^2 + 3096*x^3 + 17933*x^4 - 4432*x^5 + 27844*x^6 - 4432*x^7 + 17933*x^8 + 3096*x^9 + 4846*x^10 + 1336*x^11 + 163*x^12)*Sin[Pi/11 - 14*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(25489 - 2864*x + 137929*x^2 + 5184*x^3 + 324500*x^4 + 29760*x^5 + 540900*x^6 - 5184*x^7 + 740654*x^8 - 53792*x^9 + 740654*x^10 - 5184*x^11 + 540900*x^12 + 29760*x^13 + 324500*x^14 + 5184*x^15 + 137929*x^16 - 2864*x^17 + 25489*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 12*x] - 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12671 + 1126*x + 106967*x^2 + 3840*x^3 + 386652*x^4 - 8440*x^5 + 792300*x^6 - 4480*x^7 + 1060706*x^8 + 15908*x^9 + 1060706*x^10 - 4480*x^11 + 792300*x^12 - 8440*x^13 + 386652*x^14 + 3840*x^15 + 106967*x^16 + 1126*x^17 + 12671*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 10*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16381 - 278*x + 72181*x^2 + 1872*x^3 + 153700*x^4 - 2344*x^5 + 244532*x^6 - 3024*x^7 + 299638*x^8 + 7548*x^9 + 299638*x^10 - 3024*x^11 + 244532*x^12 - 2344*x^13 + 153700*x^14 + 1872*x^15 + 72181*x^16 - 278*x^17 + 16381*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 8*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16423 - 949*x + 75359*x^2 - 2168*x^3 + 145884*x^4 + 28660*x^5 + 205484*x^6 + 6072*x^7 + 343282*x^8 - 63230*x^9 + 343282*x^10 + 6072*x^11 + 205484*x^12 + 28660*x^13 + 145884*x^14 - 2168*x^15 + 75359*x^16 - 949*x^17 + 16423*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 - 8*x] + 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52055 + 1138*x + 320735*x^2 - 2304*x^3 + 946060*x^4 - 1256*x^5 + 1770172*x^6 + 7552*x^7 + 2416002*x^8 - 10260*x^9 + 2416002*x^10 + 7552*x^11 + 1770172*x^12 - 1256*x^13 + 946060*x^14 - 2304*x^15 + 320735*x^16 + 1138*x^17 + 52055*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 6*x] - 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52293 + 643*x + 316745*x^2 + 15936*x^3 + 923528*x^4 - 17596*x^5 + 1837824*x^6 - 40320*x^7 + 2374634*x^8 + 82674*x^9 + 2374634*x^10 - 40320*x^11 + 1837824*x^12 - 17596*x^13 + 923528*x^14 + 15936*x^15 + 316745*x^16 + 643*x^17 + 52293*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 - 6*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71797 - 304*x + 276109*x^2 + 1728*x^3 + 546660*x^4 - 6848*x^5 + 802292*x^6 + 16704*x^7 + 1055654*x^8 - 22560*x^9 + 1055654*x^10 + 16704*x^11 + 802292*x^12 - 6848*x^13 + 546660*x^14 + 1728*x^15 + 276109*x^16 - 304*x^17 + 71797*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 4*x] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71135 - 2000*x + 284903*x^2 + 7552*x^3 + 501100*x^4 + 15168*x^5 + 892828*x^6 - 96640*x^7 + 1002546*x^8 + 151840*x^9 + 1002546*x^10 - 96640*x^11 + 892828*x^12 + 15168*x^13 + 501100*x^14 + 7552*x^15 + 284903*x^16 - 2000*x^17 + 71135*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 - 4*x] - 88*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24861 + 95*x + 133003*x^2 - 544*x^3 + 356438*x^4 + 1364*x^5 + 658074*x^6 - 2080*x^7 + 892008*x^8 + 2330*x^9 + 892008*x^10 - 2080*x^11 + 658074*x^12 + 1364*x^13 + 356438*x^14 - 544*x^15 + 133003*x^16 + 95*x^17 + 24861*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 - 2*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49678 + 313*x + 263726*x^2 + 2432*x^3 + 721096*x^4 - 13172*x^5 + 1305608*x^6 + 25792*x^7 + 1788660*x^8 - 30730*x^9 + 1788660*x^10 + 25792*x^11 + 1305608*x^12 - 13172*x^13 + 721096*x^14 + 2432*x^15 + 263726*x^16 + 313*x^17 + 49678*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 - 2*x] - 88*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24933 + 132587*x^2 + 357438*x^4 + 656850*x^6 + 892576*x^8 + 892576*x^10 + 656850*x^12 + 357438*x^14 + 132587*x^16 + 24933*x^18)*Sin[2*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71095 + 279167*x^2 + 540620*x^4 + 809084*x^6 + 1052546*x^8 + 1052546*x^10 + 809084*x^12 + 540620*x^14 + 279167*x^16 + 71095*x^18)*Sin[4*x] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52469 + 321557*x^2 + 939580*x^4 + 1780540*x^6 + 2410878*x^8 + 2410878*x^10 + 1780540*x^12 + 939580*x^14 + 321557*x^16 + 52469*x^18)*Sin[6*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16415 + 72039*x^2 + 155692*x^4 + 239068*x^6 + 303218*x^8 + 303218*x^10 + 239068*x^12 + 155692*x^14 + 72039*x^16 + 16415*x^18)*Sin[8*x] - 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12349 + 111213*x^2 + 386380*x^4 + 778028*x^6 + 1071326*x^8 + 1071326*x^10 + 778028*x^12 + 386380*x^14 + 111213*x^16 + 12349*x^18)*Sin[10*x] + 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24619 + 134995*x^2 + 343772*x^4 + 566732*x^6 + 699354*x^8 + 699354*x^10 + 566732*x^12 + 343772*x^14 + 134995*x^16 + 24619*x^18)*Sin[12*x] + 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(309 + 7714*x^2 + 19099*x^4 + 19484*x^6 + 19099*x^8 + 7714*x^10 + 309*x^12)*Sin[14*x] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(277 + 428*x^2 + 638*x^4 + 428*x^6 + 277*x^8)*Sin[16*x] + 11264*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 4*x^2 + x^4)*Sin[18*x] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[20*x] + 1024*(1 + x^2)^11*Sin[22*x] + 
   88*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24861 - 95*x + 133003*x^2 + 544*x^3 + 356438*x^4 - 1364*x^5 + 658074*x^6 + 2080*x^7 + 892008*x^8 - 2330*x^9 + 892008*x^10 + 2080*x^11 + 658074*x^12 - 1364*x^13 + 356438*x^14 + 544*x^15 + 133003*x^16 - 95*x^17 + 24861*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 2*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(49678 - 313*x + 263726*x^2 - 2432*x^3 + 721096*x^4 + 13172*x^5 + 1305608*x^6 - 25792*x^7 + 1788660*x^8 + 30730*x^9 + 1788660*x^10 - 25792*x^11 + 1305608*x^12 + 13172*x^13 + 721096*x^14 - 2432*x^15 + 263726*x^16 - 313*x^17 + 49678*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 + 2*x] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71797 + 304*x + 276109*x^2 - 1728*x^3 + 546660*x^4 + 6848*x^5 + 802292*x^6 - 16704*x^7 + 1055654*x^8 + 22560*x^9 + 1055654*x^10 - 16704*x^11 + 802292*x^12 + 6848*x^13 + 546660*x^14 - 1728*x^15 + 276109*x^16 + 304*x^17 + 71797*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 4*x] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(71135 + 2000*x + 284903*x^2 - 7552*x^3 + 501100*x^4 - 15168*x^5 + 892828*x^6 + 96640*x^7 + 1002546*x^8 - 151840*x^9 + 1002546*x^10 + 96640*x^11 + 892828*x^12 - 15168*x^13 + 501100*x^14 - 7552*x^15 + 284903*x^16 + 2000*x^17 + 71135*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 + 4*x] - 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52055 - 1138*x + 320735*x^2 + 2304*x^3 + 946060*x^4 + 1256*x^5 + 1770172*x^6 - 7552*x^7 + 2416002*x^8 + 10260*x^9 + 2416002*x^10 - 7552*x^11 + 1770172*x^12 + 1256*x^13 + 946060*x^14 + 2304*x^15 + 320735*x^16 - 1138*x^17 + 52055*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 6*x] + 22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(52293 - 643*x + 316745*x^2 - 15936*x^3 + 923528*x^4 + 17596*x^5 + 1837824*x^6 + 40320*x^7 + 2374634*x^8 - 82674*x^9 + 2374634*x^10 + 40320*x^11 + 1837824*x^12 + 17596*x^13 + 923528*x^14 - 15936*x^15 + 316745*x^16 - 643*x^17 + 52293*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 + 6*x] + 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16381 + 278*x + 72181*x^2 - 1872*x^3 + 153700*x^4 + 2344*x^5 + 244532*x^6 + 3024*x^7 + 299638*x^8 - 7548*x^9 + 299638*x^10 + 3024*x^11 + 244532*x^12 + 2344*x^13 + 153700*x^14 - 1872*x^15 + 72181*x^16 + 278*x^17 + 16381*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 8*x] - 44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(16423 + 949*x + 75359*x^2 + 2168*x^3 + 145884*x^4 - 28660*x^5 + 205484*x^6 - 6072*x^7 + 343282*x^8 + 63230*x^9 + 343282*x^10 - 6072*x^11 + 205484*x^12 - 28660*x^13 + 145884*x^14 + 2168*x^15 + 75359*x^16 + 949*x^17 + 16423*x^18)*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 + 8*x] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12671 - 1126*x + 106967*x^2 - 3840*x^3 + 386652*x^4 + 8440*x^5 + 792300*x^6 + 4480*x^7 + 1060706*x^8 - 15908*x^9 + 1060706*x^10 + 4480*x^11 + 792300*x^12 + 8440*x^13 + 386652*x^14 - 3840*x^15 + 106967*x^16 - 1126*x^17 + 12671*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 10*x] - 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(25489 + 2864*x + 137929*x^2 - 5184*x^3 + 324500*x^4 - 29760*x^5 + 540900*x^6 + 5184*x^7 + 740654*x^8 + 53792*x^9 + 740654*x^10 + 5184*x^11 + 540900*x^12 - 29760*x^13 + 324500*x^14 - 5184*x^15 + 137929*x^16 + 2864*x^17 + 25489*x^18)*Sin[Pi/11 + 12*x] - 
   44*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(163 - 1336*x + 4846*x^2 - 3096*x^3 + 17933*x^4 + 4432*x^5 + 27844*x^6 + 4432*x^7 + 17933*x^8 - 3096*x^9 + 4846*x^10 - 1336*x^11 + 163*x^12)*Sin[Pi/11 + 14*x] + 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(221 - 176*x + 76*x^2 - 976*x^3 - 850*x^4 - 976*x^5 + 76*x^6 - 176*x^7 + 221*x^8)*Sin[Pi/11 + 16*x] + 5632*x*(1 + x)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 + 6*x - 6*x^2 + 6*x^3 + x^4)*Sin[Pi/11 + 18*x] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[Pi/11 + 20*x] + 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[(2*Pi)/11 + 20*x] + 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12691 - 163*x + 109863*x^2 - 832*x^3 + 383904*x^4 - 1732*x^5 + 782968*x^6 + 2688*x^7 + 1069870*x^8 + 78*x^9 + 1069870*x^10 + 2688*x^11 + 782968*x^12 - 1732*x^13 + 383904*x^14 - 832*x^15 + 109863*x^16 - 163*x^17 + 12691*x^18)*Sin[(5/11)*(Pi + 22*x)] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24569 + 64*x + 135985*x^2 + 512*x^3 + 345204*x^4 + 2816*x^5 + 565188*x^6 - 512*x^7 + 698526*x^8 - 5760*x^9 + 698526*x^10 - 512*x^11 + 565188*x^12 + 2816*x^13 + 345204*x^14 + 512*x^15 + 135985*x^16 + 64*x^17 + 24569*x^18)*Sin[(4/11)*(Pi + 33*x)] - 
   11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(24747 + 1472*x + 141523*x^2 + 16640*x^3 + 386524*x^4 + 96000*x^5 + 742092*x^6 + 278272*x^7 + 1064410*x^8 + 394880*x^9 + 1064410*x^10 + 278272*x^11 + 742092*x^12 + 96000*x^13 + 386524*x^14 + 16640*x^15 + 141523*x^16 + 1472*x^17 + 24747*x^18)*Sin[(3/11)*(Pi + 44*x)] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(247 + 612*x^2 + 330*x^4 + 612*x^6 + 247*x^8)*Sin[(4/11)*(Pi + 44*x)] - 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[(5/11)*(Pi + 44*x)] - 
   22*(-1 + x^2)^2*(12221 - 3473*x + 96577*x^2 - 38720*x^3 + 312232*x^4 - 91180*x^5 + 724000*x^6 + 37632*x^7 + 1214266*x^8 + 191482*x^9 + 1214266*x^10 + 37632*x^11 + 724000*x^12 - 91180*x^13 + 312232*x^14 - 38720*x^15 + 96577*x^16 - 3473*x^17 + 12221*x^18)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi + 55*x)] + 2816*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^9*Sin[(4/11)*(Pi + 55*x)] + 11*(-1 + x^2)^2*(23859 - 5056*x + 114715*x^2 - 69376*x^3 + 157564*x^4 - 406272*x^5 - 170772*x^6 - 1110272*x^7 - 715190*x^8 - 1536640*x^9 - 715190*x^10 - 1110272*x^11 - 170772*x^12 - 406272*x^13 + 157564*x^14 - 69376*x^15 + 114715*x^16 - 5056*x^17 + 23859*x^18)*
    Sin[(2/11)*(Pi + 66*x)] - 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Sin[(3/11)*(Pi + 66*x)] + 44*(1 + x)^2*(1 + x^2)^3*(473 - 498*x + 9059*x^2 - 13716*x^3 + 30401*x^4 - 26670*x^5 + 54275*x^6 - 24728*x^7 + 54275*x^8 - 26670*x^9 + 30401*x^10 - 13716*x^11 + 9059*x^12 - 498*x^13 + 473*x^14)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi + 77*x)] - 176*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^5*(249 + 16*x + 668*x^2 + 112*x^3 + 470*x^4 + 112*x^5 + 668*x^6 + 16*x^7 + 249*x^8)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi + 88*x)] + 704*(-1 + x^2)^2*(1 + x^2)^7*(1 - 34*x^2 + x^4)*Sin[(2/11)*(Pi + 99*x)])
```

using `Plot[ConditionalExpression[1, -3 <= compiledfunc[x] <= 3], {x, 12,  13}, PlotPoints -> 100000, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.007]], Axes ->{False, False}]`, I get
[image]

Comment: **when I set the mentioned items a big number, it takes a lot of time** That is really to be expected, If you set `PlotPoints -> 1000, MaxRecursion -> 15` it will take much longer than `PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 2`.

Comment: @Nasser That is why I am looking for an alternative since small numbers for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` does not help me. Actually, I ran `PlotPoints-> 200000` and `MaxRecursion-> 15`, and `WorkingPrecision->500` on a PC and I am waiting for the result but I need to do this for a large number of functions so it might be disappointing.

Comment: Why did you use `Func:=` instead of `Func=` ?

Comment: @userrandrand It was just a mistake. Does this $:=$ increase timing?

Comment: := means that no evaluations are done on the right side until the function is evaluated in an another cell. In Func there is nothing to evaluate so I would not expect any significant time difference when compared to =. I just did not see why you did not use Func= instead as I did not notice any particular reason to use :=.

Comment: Since you are new, allow me to add the point that a good practice is not to use capitals when naming things. Only internally named functions and constants start with capitals, then, and you avoid clashes with items like `I`, `N`, `D`, `E`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will address 3 points:

- There is a pole that is easy to remove.
- The function is very long you might want to compile it.
- I do not understand why you want such high precision in a plot but there are other ways to obtain those lines

---

#### Removing the poles from the analysis

The function has poles from the `Csc` function. They can be removed by considering instead the function:

```
deflated = Func[x]/Csc[x]^11;
```

I placed an explantion of how I found that at the end of this section and before the next section.

Then, instead of considering the equation `Func[x]==3` for example we can consider `deflated==3*Sin[x]^11` or `deflated-3*Sin[x]^11` which is a non singular equation in the interval you are considering (note there are still poles at x=1 and x=-1).

---

*How I found that in that long expression:*

I checked the different types of functions by using

```
Cases[Func[x], _[_], All] // DeleteDuplicates
```

I noticed the `Csc`. I looked for its positions in the expression using:

```
Position[Func[x], Csc[x]]
```

I obtained `{{4, 1}}`

```
Func[x][[4]]
```

evaluates to

`Csc[x]^11`

I checked the Head of Func and saw it is times, I check the number of terms with `Length` and used `//Together //Denominator` on the most complicated term to check that there are no other poles

---

---

#### Compilation

**It turns out that your problem seems to require high accuracy** which `Compile` does not support see however posts on stack exchange that use NumericalFunction to obtain high accuracy.

Also, in the next section `NDSolve` will be use and there was no benefit in using compilation. As I understand, `NDSolve` compiles automatically when it sees fit. For a discussion about that see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962178/does-an-ode-written-using-gnu-gsl-outperform-mathematicas-ndsolve). The benefit of compilation here is if you really want to use plot.

(see update mentions in bold)

Compiling is tricky because not all functions can be compiled and in the default setting of `Compile` it will not display any error if it skips compilation and just evaluates the function as usual. To make compile complain if something is wrong :

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True];
On[Compile::noinfo]
```

I do not remember what each one does I just remember I saved them for whenever I want to compile a function. If you are interested see this reference on stack exchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions?lq=1)

I changed `Func:=` to `Func[x_]:=` because I do not see the point of `Func:=` in that expression. To compile the function one may use:

**Note:** `…=\[Ellipsis]`

**update**

```
deflated…compiled = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate@deflated];
```

Test the speed difference:

**update**

```
RepeatedTiming[
  deflated…compiled[
    RandomReal[{11, 16}]];] // ScientificForm 

RepeatedTiming[deflated /. x -> RandomReal[{11, 16}];] // 
  ScientificForm // TeXForm
```

$$\left\{2.31868\times
   10^{-5},\text{Null}\right\}$$

$$\left\{1.46028\times
   10^{-3},\text{Null}\right\}$$

So you might expect a 10 to 100 times speed up.

---

#### Alternative method using `NDSolve` (updated)

To obtain crossings of a function $f$ one can solve the differential equation:

$$y'(x)=f'(x), \qquad y(x_{\text{min}})=f(x_{\text{min}})$$

such that $y(x)=f(x)$ and use `WhenEvent` to detect special points such as crossings. We will compare the compile and non compiled case.

The crossing condition can be written as :

```
Abs[deflated]==Abs[3*Sin[x]^11]
```

where `Abs` was introduced to incorporate both `Func[x]==3` and `Func[x]==-3`

**Default precision**

Solve the differential equation with `WhenEvent`:

```
xmin = 11;
xmax = 16; AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Reap[
    NDSolve[{s'[x] == ddeflated, s[xmin] == (deflated /. x -> xmin), 
      WhenEvent[Abs[s[x]] == Abs[3*Sin[x]^11], Sow[x]]}, 
     s, {x, xmin, xmax}]];]
```

Timing: 0.12 seconds

Check:

```
Plot[Abs[s[x]] - Abs[3*Sin[x]^11] /. res[[1, 1, 1]], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{#, 0} & /@ res[[2, 1]]]}]
```

> The red points bellow represent the crossings `Func[x]==3` or
> `Func[x]==-3` which are translated to zeroes of the functions
> considered in the plot.

[image]

Notice that there are no zeroes in the interval you showed in your update. This is in fact an artifact here of low precision and there are indeed 0's in that interval.

- **High Precision**

Solve the differential equation (I did not check if a lower precision is enough) :

```
xmin = 11;
xmax = 16; AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Reap[
    NDSolve[{s'[x] == ddeflated, s[xmin] == (deflated /. x -> xmin), 
      WhenEvent[Abs[s[x]] == Abs[3*Sin[x]^11], Sow[x]]}, 
     s, {x, xmin, xmax}, PrecisionGoal -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 20]];]
```

Timing :  13.4 seconds

```
Plot[Abs[s[x]] - Abs[3*Sin[x]^11] /. res[[1, 1, 1]], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{#, 0} & /@ res[[2, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

The points can be also viewed with `NumberLinePlot` :

```
res[[2, 1]] // NumberLinePlot
```

[image]

We can extract the points between 12 and 13 :

```
Select[res[[2, 1]], 12 < # < 13 &]
```

`{12.461458413778561480, 12.461645303474289146, 12.473084286833757123, \ 12.474549028597047319, 12.477815775272624841, 12.481004423258161594, \ 12.482612164386612858, 12.487570045422328843, 12.660291420025539393, \ 12.668827725840002865}`

From those points you could just draw the lines with [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) and [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

Comment: @Phys96 did you use `ConditionalExpression[1, -3 <= compiledfunc <= 3]` or `ConditionalExpression[1, -3 <= compiledfunc[x] <= 3]` in the plot ? It should be `-3 <= compiledfunc[x] <= 3`

Comment: What alternative ? `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent` ?

Comment: @Phys96 I meant did you specify `compiledfunc[x]` instead of just `compiledfunc` in the plot

Comment: On my computer it works with `compiledfunc[x]`

Comment: Did you check references for how to use `WhenEvent` like that ? It is a known trick more than a standard procedure

Comment: Sorry, how can I use NDSolve on D[Func[x],x]==0? I am beginner at Mathematica.

Comment: @Phys96 it has the same precision when using the default working precision. However it is unable to compute high precision for example check the difference between the compiled and non compile versions on `N[Pi/4,40]`

Comment: I never used Compile for high precision but you can search here for "Compile Precision". For example [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102475/is-there-any-way-to-use-compile-and-still-maintain-high-precision-in-mathematica)

Comment: There is also a new compiler for Mathematica but I do not know how to use it. It supports 64 bit double precision see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Typed.html)

Comment: @Phys96 sorry You should use NDSolve and WhenEvent on y'[x]==D[Func[x],x]  that way the solution y[x] if the function Func and you can use WhenEvent to detect crossings as NDSolve traces out the points.

Comment: @Phys96 sure and I corrected what I wrote in the previous comment the differential equation is `y'[x]= D[Func[x],x]`

Comment: @Phys96 I tried using `NDSolve` directly with `Func` and the poles in `Func` caused an issue which is why I rewrote the equation in my answer.

Comment: @Phys96 I checked again with higher precision using `PrecisionGoal -> 18, AccuracyGoal -> 18, WorkingPrecision -> 30` and restricting to the interval [12, 13] and I got the points `{12.4782422498640194218621429941, 12.4880185884391964508073214141, \
12.6602135218810309526143122185, 12.6687845842000445421616946743, \
12.6738359497622442984463355558, 12.6742790429661863361550911413}`

Comment: The position and number of crossings seem to depend highly on the precision choices. You should maybe play around with the precision until you have something convincing.