# FindMinimum with LevenbergMarquardt Method: syntax to set lower/higher bounds for parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I use the LevenbergMarquardt method of the FindMinimum function to minimize a residual function (mathematical-optimization). The 2013 post [Is it possible to use the LevenbergMarquardt (LM) algorithm for fitting a black-box residual function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/is-it-possible-to-use-the-levenbergmarquardt-algorithm-for-fitting-a-black-box-r) was very helpful to determine how to use the LM algorithm.

Now, I would like to set upper and lower bounds for the three parameters I need to optimize, but I was not able to find any information in Mathematica Help or online on how to do this. 
Does anyone know if this is possible ?
what would be the correct syntax ?

Thaks for your help !

Comment: Please, post a minimal example demonstrating the behaviour you are after.

Comment: please post your code here.

Answer (score 5):

The `"LevenbergMarquardt"` `Method` is an [unconstrained optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html) algorithm, so it does not allow setting bounds for the parameters. If you need to set bounds you should use one of the algorithms for [constrained optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).

The correct syntax for local constrained optimization is given on the Documentation page for `FindMinimum`:

> ```
> FindMinimum[{f[x,y,...], cons}, {{x,x0}, {y,y0}, ...}]
> ```
>
> searches for a local minimum subject to the constraints `cons` starting from the points `x = x0`, `y = y0` ...

The function `f[x,y,...]` can be a black-box function defined via one of the forms of the "black box" pattern, for example:

```
f[x_Real, y_Real, z_Real] := ...
```