# Using the Levenberg - Marquardt algorithm to minimize a user-defined function

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I wrote a function in Matlab that optimizes another user defined function using `lsqnonlin` with 'levenberg-marquardt' option. Now, I'd like to use the first to optimize a user defined function written in *Mathematica*.

An alternative solution would be to explain how to use Levenberg - Marquardt optimization in *Mathematica* because I searched a lot about it and can't understand how to use it.

The objective function takes a vector of 4 elements and returns a vector of 6 elements.I don't know how to express the output as a sum of squares.
I want it to be closer to zero as possible.

---

This is the main code

```
{clc , clear all, close all %c l e a r screen and v a r i a b l e s
global p N a %set global parameters p N x0 a
a (1)=0.15; %system parameter a
a (2)=0.2; %system parameter b
a (3)=3.5; %system parameter c
N=3; %s i z e of system
p=2; %i n t e g e r p i s chosen so that the s i z e of the
%r e s i d u a l i s >= than the q u a n t i t i e s to be optimized ( s i z e of
%r e s i d u a l i s given by p?N
x0 (1)=7; %i n i t i a l guess f o r x1 (0)
x0 (2)=7; %i n i t i a l guess f o r x2 (0)
x0 (3)=7; %i n i t i a l guess f o r x3 (0)
%Quantities to be optimized v0
%For t h i s case only x0 (1) , x0 (2) , x0 (3) , and T are considered
v0(1)=x0(1) ;
v0(2)=x0(2) ;
v0(3)=x0(3) ;
T=4; %i n i t i a l guess f o r period
v0(4)=T;
%Set l s q n o n l i n to implement the LMA algorithm
OPTIONS = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt','TolX',1e-16);
%,'TolX ' , 1 e ?12 , 'TolFun ' , 1 e ?12 , ' MaxIter ' , 1 0 0 0 ) ;
%Call in the r e s i d u a l function to find optimized q u a n t i t i e s
x = lsqnonlin('abcd2',v0,[],[],OPTIONS) ;}
```

And this is the objective function

```
{function R = abcd2(b0) 
global p N a
dt =1/2^10; %s e t the s t e p s i z e
% Rossler system written in dimensionless time
xdot =@(t,x)[b0(4)*(-x(2)-x(3));b0(4)*(x(1)+a(1)*x(2));b0(4)*(a(2)+x(3)*(x(1)-a(3)))];
%perform numerical i n t e g r a t i o n to f i n d x ( 1 ) , x ( dt ) , and x(1+dt )
[t,vv]=ode45(xdot,[0 1],[b0(1);b0(2);b0(3)]) ;
[t1,vv1]=ode45(xdot,[0 dt],[b0(1);b0(2);b0(3)]);
[t2,vv2]=ode45 (xdot,[0 1+dt],[b0(1);b0(2);b0(3)]);
R = zeros(p*N,1); %p r e a l l o c a t i n g f o r the r e s i d u e
k = size(vv) ; %f i n d l a s t value from i n t e g r a t i o n
k1 = size(vv1) ;
k2 = size(vv2) ;
%build r e s i d u a l
R(1)=vv(k(1),1)-b0(1); %R(1)=x1(1) -x1 (0)
R(2)=vv(k(1),2)-b0(2); %R(2)=x2(1) -x2 (0)
R(3)=vv(k(1),3)-b0(3); %R(3)=x3(1) -x3 (0)
R(4)=vv2(k2(1),1)-vv1(k1(1),1); %R(4)=x1(1+dt)-x1 ( dt )
R(5)=vv2(k2(1),2)-vv1(k1(1),2); %R(5)=x2(1+dt)-x1 ( dt )
R(6)=vv2(k2(1),3)-vv1(k1(1),3); %R(6)=x3(1+dt)-x1 ( dt )
end}
```

---

This is the function i want to optimize

```
residue[x_] := Block[{R = Table[1, {6}], dt = 2^-10, SOL},
 SOL = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == -x[[4]] (x2[t] + x3[t]), 
 x2'[t] == x[[4]] (x1[t] + 0.15 x2[t]), 
 x3'[t] == x[[4]] (0.2 + x3[t] (x1[t] - 3.5)), x1[0] == x[[1]], 
 x2[0] == x[[2]], x3[0] == x[[3]]}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 1 + dt}];
 R = {x1[1] - x[[1]], x2[1] - x[[2]], x3[1] - x[[3]], 
 x1[1 + dt] - x1[dt], x2[1 + dt] - x2[dt], 
 x3[1 + dt] - x3[dt]} /. SOL[[1]];
 Return[R];]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `FindMinimum`? You can set the optimization algorithm using `Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"`. See this tutorial on ([Introduction to Local Minimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionLocalMinimization.html)) for an introduction.

Comment: `FindMinimum[]` is able to use Levenberg-Marquardt (or Gauss-Newton) if you can express your objective function as a sum of squares. [The advanced documentation for the optimization functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationGaussNewtonMethods.html) should have a few words on this.

Comment: the function I wrote takes a vector of 4 elementsand returns a vector of 6 elements, and I don't know how to express my function output as a sum of squares. I want to optimize the input to minimize the output as possible (closer to zero).

Comment: "I don't know how to express my function output as a sum of squares." - then Levenberg-Marquardt might not even be the most appropriate optimization to use. In any event, how does one speak of a "minimum vector"? Minimum with respect to its norm? If so, which norm?

Comment: I saw a code written in matlab to optimize the same function i wrote in mathematica with the same input and the same output.
Do you have a resource about converting a vector to a sum of squares.

Comment: "I saw a code written in matlab" - where is this? For that matter, where is the *Mathematica* code that you have?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/d744d247-f51b-45a6-afe4-64ae222132d0/view-source

Comment: Please edit your original post with the information rather than post an answer. In addition, make sure that it is correctly formatted in code blocks (click the grey question mark at the right of the toolbar for help), and make sure *that it is readable*. What you have posted is impossible to decipher.

Comment: I think I have an idea of what you need to do now, but just to be sure, do you have a reference for the code you got?

Comment: i got it from a student's paper inspired from a published paper called "Optimized shooting method for finding periodic orbits
of nonlinear dynamical systems"

Comment: So you're trying to find parameters for the Rossler attractor using LM. You might be interested in using `ParametricNDSolve[]` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to find the period T and initial conditions that will solve for the periodic solution (the initial conditions that lies on the limit cycle or periodic orbit) which minimizes the residue (x(T)-x(0)) to be equal to zero

Comment: Potentially related: "[Is it possible to use the LevenbergMarquardt algorithm for fitting a black-box residual function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1954/280)"

Answer (score 1):

```
FindMinimum[3 (x - 4)^2 + 5 (y + 2)^2 - 9, {x, y}, 
 Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
```

(*
{-9., {x -> 4., y -> -2.}}
*)

Comment: the function I wrote takes a vector of 4 elements and returns a vector of 6 elements, and I don't know how to express my function output as a sum of squares. I want to optimize the input to minimize the output as possible (closer to zero).